# Deferred and promise with loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, promise, jquery-deferred

I am trying to use deferred and promises within the context of a loop and I fail doing so.

I need to call a first method asynchronously. This first method (let´s call it getArray()) returns an array.

For each element of the array, I need to call a second method, let´s call it getData(id). The id is stored in the array returned by getArray.

Finally, once I have the result of getData(), I need to use the result to call a third method, let´s call it getDetails().

Once all the calls are done and the loop is finished, I need to return the array, with extra data and details.

I created a jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/chevdor/953sLkts/

```
var myarray = [];

var log = function(s){
    $('#console').append('<p>'+s+'</p>');
};

var get1 = function() {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get1');
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var res = [1, 2, 3, 4];

        // that´s probably crap...
        for (var i= 0; i< res.length; i++){
            get2(res[i])
                .done(get3(res[i])
                    .done(get4(res[i]))
            );
        }

        dfd.resolve(res);
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

var get2 = function(index) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get2');

    setTimeout(function() { 
        var res = {
            index: index,
            val: index * 2
        };
        myarray[index]= res;
        dfd.resolve(res);
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

var get3 = function(index) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get3');

    setTimeout(function() { 
        var res = {
            index: index,
            val2: index * index
        };
        myarray[index].extra =  res;

        dfd.resolve(res);
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

var get4 = function(index) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get4');

    setTimeout(function() { // Resolve after a random interval
        var res = {
            index: index,
            val2: index * index
        };
        dfd.resolve(res);
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

log('start');
get1();
```

to illustrate. It definitely does not work and look ugly...

Can you explain what would be the proper way to do that?

Comment: Please make the code the shortest possible to reproduce the issue - if you do I'll add an answer. A good start for a solution would be to call `.then` and not `done` and to pass it a function (as then and done take) and not a promise.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I don´t understand how I can get rid of the promises for get2 and get3. They contain async code and the only way around I can think of would be to use callbacks. This is precisely what I am trying to avoid to void callback hell.

Comment: @Chevdor Is `var res = [1, 2, 3, 4]` at `get1` "array" at _"I need to call a first method asynchronously. This first method (let´s call it getArray()) returns an array."_ ? `4` not appear passed to function ?

Comment: Instead of setting values into an array, your promises should resolve with the results, like `get4` does it. The caller of those functions can still put them into `myArray` if he wants to.

Comment: It would be nice if you could use meaningful names in your code as well, like the `getData` or `getDetails` you referred to in your text.

Comment: My explanation was bad... I am working on it thanks to you guys. Thank you all for your patience!

All the methods I need to call below are async.
The first method I need to call returns an array: getArray(). 
Once I have this array, I need to call getData() on each element.

Then once I have the result of getData(), I can call getDetails() which grabs a little more data for each elem of the array. getDetails() needs the result from getData().

At the end, once I got data and details for each element of the array, I would like to return the result which is the array with the additional data.

Comment: No time to write a proper answer - [here's a fun approach](http://jsfiddle.net/8wpm1nhn/2/).

Answer (score 1):

May I introduce you to $.when.

From your code, it looks like your get2(), get3(), get4() are the getData(), getDetail(). Assume they all are made like a promise. Then you can do this:

```
getArray().then(function(array){
    var allpromises=_.map(array,function(one){
        var toReturn={id:one}
        // let's assume the array is [1,2,3...]; then one= 1,2,3...
        return getData(one).then(function(onedata){ 
            //onedata={name:'foo',id:1} just an example.
            toReturn['data']=onedata;
            return getDetail(onedata);
        }).then(function(detail){ // here you get detail
            toReturn['detail']=detail;
            return jQuery.resolve(toReturn);
        });
    });
    return jQuery.when(allpromises); // This is a promise, resolves when every promise in the array all resolved. the resolved data is the same length array (same length as the allpromises. 
}).then(function(dataarray){
    console.log(dataarray); //each entry should be like the "toReturn". {id:1,data:{name:'foo',id:1},detail:{object}}
})
```

I was a big fan of bluebird promise, the keyword was .all() instead of .when(). I am not exactly sure how jquery promise work, but I believe it is a very similar structure. Hope this helps. Let me know if it is unclear :)

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion, to use $.when on array of promises, the syntax is:

```
$.when.apply($, [promise1,promise2,promise3]).then(function(data){
})
```

Note the "data" here is only the resolved from promise1, I am not familiar with jquery. But I do recommend [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) promise. Which is faster and cleaner.

Comment: Hi Evilsanta (brrrrr! :) )
You are right about the method names, sorry for the confusion. Trying to simplify I made is more complex to explain. I did not test yet but your sample seems promising! I will test that and validate your answer if that works. Thanks already for your answer.

Comment: @Chevdor sorry I made a mistake with the $when. it is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array `p` , `.push()` results of `$.when(get2(res[i]), get3(res[i]), get4(res[i]))` to `p` ; call `$.when.apply` with `p` as array of jQuery promise objects passed ; check results of `dfd.resolve(res)` , `myarray` at `.then` `onFulfilled` handler of `get1`

```js
var myarray = [];

var log = function(s){
    $('#console').append('<p>'+s+'</p>');
};

var get1 = function() {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get1');
    var p = [];
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var res = [1, 2, 3, 4];

        // that´s probably crap...
  for (var i= 0; i< res.length; i++){
   p.push($.when(get2(res[i]), get3(res[i])
            , get4(res[i])))
            
  };
        
        $.when.apply($, p).then(function() {
          dfd.resolve($.makeArray(arguments))
        })
        
        
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

var get2 = function(index) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get2');

    setTimeout(function() { 
        var res = {
            index: index,
            val: index * 2
        };
        myarray[index]= res;
        dfd.resolve(res);
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

var get3 = function(index) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get3');

    setTimeout(function() { 
        var res = {
            index: index,
            val2: index * index
        };
        myarray[index] = {"extra":res};
        
        dfd.resolve(res);
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

var get4 = function(index) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    log('Running get4');

    setTimeout(function() { // Resolve after a random interval
        var res = {
            index: index,
            val2: index * index
        };
        dfd.resolve(res);
    }, Math.floor(400 + Math.random() * 1000));
    return dfd.promise();
};

log('start');
get1().then(function() {
  console.log("res:", arguments, "myarray:", myarray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<h1>Test</h1>
<span id='console'></span>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/953sLkts/9/

Comment: Where's the loop gone? Also the promise returned by `get1()` resolves wrong

Comment: @Bergi The way loop was structured appear not necessary ? where parameters passed appear to be `1`, `2`, `3`  ? `4` does not appear to be passed to a function returning a jQuery promise object at OP ? _"Also the promise returned by get1()  resolves wrong"_ Not certain interpret meaning of "resolves wrong" ?, can describe ? See _"This first method (let´s call it getArray()) returns an array."_ Should `res` be resolved after `get4` ? so array could be returned promise value at potential `.then` at `get1` ?

Comment: @Bergi Ah, initial `res` at `get1` at OP is example of _"This first method (let´s call it getArray()) returns an array."_ ?

Comment: @Bergi There appear to be three functions defined though four array elements returned ? Perhaps should create single function to handle all element `id`s from `getArray` , adding condition for `val: index * 2` at `get2` ?

Comment: I mean that the promise returned by `get1` resolves immediately, instead of waiting for the other `get*` calls. Of course that's the same mistake the OP did; I guess he didn't mean it.

Comment: Re: the loop - I think the OP wants to call all the three functions four times (or however many items are in that `res` array), each call with a different value.

Comment: @Bergi See updated post. Not certain if both `res` and `myarray` expected return values from `get1` ? though `myarray` should be available at `get1` `.then` handler even if not explicitly returned at `get1`

Comment: That´s right. First I get the array. Then I need to call a function on each element of the array (which gives extra data) and finally a last function, based on the extra data I just got. Once all data is collected, I return or call a cb.

Comment: @Chevdor Does `js` at attempted solution return expected results ?, resolve Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 it looks good I must say but ```console.log("res:", arguments, "myarray:", myarray);``` never shows up so something must be wrong.

Comment: @Chevdor _"but console.log("res:", arguments, "myarray:", myarray); never shows up so something must be wrong."_  Can describe "never shows up" ? Tried stacksnippets, above ? , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/953sLkts/9/ ? `js` appear to return `res: [Array[4]] myarray: [1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object] ` at `console` , here.